# Spring Batch as ETL for Call Data Record Loading in to DB -Telecom

Tags: cloud, etl, spring-batch, gridgain

If anyone can share information ,about spring batch used as an ETL Tools. Specifically in Telecom Companies for Call Data Record loading (CDR's) from Network switch.In House ETL developed using spring batch.

1. What is the performance in production ?
2. Any Cloud Computing platform used with Spring batch to acheive scalability.?

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here, as management of CDRs may need specific treatements through the ETL process: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like this proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal

Answer (score 1):

SpringBatch is dead simple for a Java Dev to write ETL jobs, quite possibly simpler and more maintainable than a dedicated ETL tool like SSIS.

I can't give detailed info on performance because all of the larger jobs I'm running are constrained by network latency rather than the app itself, but the smaller extract-type jobs (~10K records) usually run in 3-5 seconds, most of which is loading and reading config.

It's also [easily configurable for multi-threaded use](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html), although you'd have to write some of your own reader and writer classes as those provided with the framework are usually not thread-safe.

If you have any specific questions, I'd be happy to try to answer them.